# Difficulty with Complex Computation in Proof on Ford Spheres

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, gaussian-integers, research

I am reading a paper on arXiv taking the idea of Ford circles and putting it into three dimensions, but am having difficulty with the following lemma, at a very basic level. Most of the details aren't relevant to my issue. What's important is that $\omega$ is the root of unity $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$.

[image]

Now, everything here works for me except for $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{b+c+c\omega}{a+b+c}$. ${|\beta|}^2$ is in fact $a+b+c$, so $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{\alpha\bar{\beta}}{{|\beta|}^2}=\frac{(x+y\omega)(u-v\omega)}{a+b+c}=\frac{xu+yu\omega-xv\omega+yv(1+\omega)}{a+b+c}=\frac{xu+yv+(yu-xv+yv)\omega}{a+b+c}$, since $-\omega^2=1+\omega$. Now, $b+c=xu+yv-xv$ and $c=yu-xv$, which are not the real and $\omega$ parts of $\alpha\bar{\beta}$. So this can't hold in the generality required. So I was wondering if there's something obvious I'm misunderstanding, or some obvious modification that can be made to $a,b,c,d$ to get it to work or if I should just give up on it.

Comment: Hello, I am not here to answer but rather to point out that your title should be a **lot** clearer! You need to title it with something relevant to the issue and context e.g. “difficulty with complex arithmetic in Ford circles” so that those in the know can see your title and be attracted, and you can get the help you want

Comment: Very interesting (I have been working on Ford circles). Could you give the reference of this arXiv file ?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00813 Among other things it parametrizes the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers with tangent spheres. (Which naturally begs the question of whether $n$-tuples of rational numbers can be parametrized by tangent hyperspheres.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that you have $\beta=u+v\omega$ and that you continue with $\overline{\beta}=u-v\omega$, which is not correct. Note that $\overline{\omega}=\omega^2=-1-\omega$.

Comment: I spent literally 30 minutes staring at this. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I also needed a second view :)